# How to upload a folder and its subdirectories to a Dropbox account?

Tags: java, file, recursion, dropbox-api

I'm currently able to upload files to a Dropbox account using the Dropbox API using the following code.

```
DbxEntry.File result = client.uploadFile("/" + inputFile.getName(), DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), inputStream);
```

But how do I upload a folder and its subdirectory and files using the Dropbox API? I tried the below steps to upload the entire folder and sub folders:

1. List content of the local directory.
2. For each item in the local directory:
3. If the item is a file, upload the file to the server.
4. If the item is a directory:
5. Create the directory on the server.
6. Upload this sub directory by repeating the step 1, 2 and 3.
7. Return if the directory is empty or if the last item is processed

But the above steps results in `FileNotFoundException` for folders when I try to open the folder recursively in `inputstream`.

Comment: The steps you described sound right, so I assume your code has a bug in it. If you share your code, maybe someone can help spot the issue. One possible hint from your description: "when I try to open the folder recursively in inputstream"... you wouldn't use an `InputStream` to "open" a folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use two of my projects to achieve this:

- [java7-fs-dropbox](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-dropbox) (which uses the dropbox API);
- [java7-fs-more](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-more).

Instructions to set up the first of these projects are in its README, and once you're done, it will be as simple as:

```
final Path srcdir = Paths.get("dir/on/your/disk");
try (
    final FileSystem dropboxfs = seeReadmeForInstructions();
) {
    final Path dstdir = dropboxfs.getPath("/target/dir");
    Files.createDirectories(dstdir);
    MoreFiles.copyRecursive(srcdir, dstdir, RecursionMode.FAIL_FAST);
}
```